# Как создать Post запрос на HTTPS?

Tags: c#

У меня есть данные для доступа в yandex api.

```
ID: 2114e92fd3a14be6942e76445070c500
Пароль: 3e7867c5b1a943cb905a3822eb7f3bfffc
Callback URL: https://oauth.yandex.ru/verification_code
```

Как мне с этими данными создать post запрос и получить данные?

Синтаксис запроса в Яндекс апи описан так -

```
POST /api2/registrar/email/add
Host: pddimp.yandex.ru
PddToken: <ПДД-токен>
Authorization: OAuth <OAuth-токен>
...

domain=<имя домена>
&login=<логин почтового ящика>
&password=<пароль>
```

Тут речь идет о создании почтового ящика в нашем домене.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы показали - идентификатор и пароль зарегистрированного OAuth-приложения регистратора доменных имён. Нужен он только если вы не являетесь владельцем домена, а являетесь регистратором - полностью отдельной компанией-субподрядчиком, которая занимается услугами по регистрации яндекс-почты для других организаций.

Однако судя по тексту, оно вам это ни к чему, т.к. вы - представитель владельца домена.

Вам достаточно получить ПДД-токен администратора домена. Для этого нужно зайти в в [управление доменами](https://pdd.yandex.ru/) под учетной записью администратора домена, перейти на страницу [управления токенами](https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/get_token), ввести капчу и доменное имя, да нажать на кнопку получения токена. В результате вы получите ПДД-токен - строку вида `0123456789ABCDEF01234567890ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF012`

А дальше, можно использовать, например, простенькую надстройку поверх стандартного `HttpClient`:

```
namespace Yandex.PDD
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class Client : HttpClient
    {
        private class EmailAddAnswer
        {
            public string domain { get; set; }
            public string login { get; set; }
            public long uid { get; set; }
            public string success { get; set; }
            public string error { get; set; }
        }

        public Client(string token)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/");
            DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PddToken", token);
        }

        public long EmailAdd(string domain, string login, string password)
        {
            return EmailAddAsync(domain, login, password).Result;
        }

        public async Task<long> EmailAddAsync(string domain, string login, string password)
        {
            var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "domain", domain },
                { "login", login },
                { "password", password }
            };

            var response = await PostAsync("email/add", new FormUrlEncodedContent(fields));
            var answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailAddAnswer>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            if (answer.success == "error")
            {
                throw new Exception(answer.error);
            }
            else
            {
                return answer.uid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var client = new Yandex.PDD.Client("0123456789ABCDEF01234567890ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF012");
var uid = client.EmailAdd("example.com", "vasya", "SuperStrongPassword");
```