# Как сделать HTTPS запрос с помощью метода GET с токеном?

Tags: c#

Хочу получить список почтовых ящик с нашего домена, токен у меня есть. 
Есть синтаксис запроса:

```
GET /api2/admin/email/list?
domain=<имя домена>
[&page=<номер страницы ответа>]
[&on_page=<количество почтовых ящиков на каждой странице ответа>]

Host: pddimp.yandex.ru
PddToken: <ПДД-токен>
```

Я пока еще учусь не совсем понимаю логику запросов, особенно таких. Прошу объяснить, как создается запрос, как в нем используется токен и как получить ответ от сервера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дополню код из своего [предыдущего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435150/17298):

```
namespace Yandex.PDD
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class Client : HttpClient
    {
        public Client(string token)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/");
            DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PddToken", token);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Account> EmailList(string domain)
        {
            int page = 0;
            int pages = 0;

            do
            {
                var call = string.Format("email/list?domain={0}&page={1}", domain, ++page);

                // С одной стороны - хочется использовать yeld,
                // А с другой - асинхронность
                // Как жаль, что они не совместимы =/
                var response = GetAsync(call).Result;
                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailListAnswer>(json);
                CheckAnswer(answer);

                pages = answer.pages;

                foreach (var account in answer.accounts)
                {
                    yield return account;
                }
            } while (pages > page);
        }

        public long EmailAdd(string domain, string login, string password)
        {
            return EmailAddAsync(domain, login, password).Result;
        }

        public async Task<long> EmailAddAsync(string domain, string login, string password)
        {
            var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "domain", domain },
                    { "login", login },
                    { "password", password }
                };

            var response = await PostAsync("email/add", new FormUrlEncodedContent(fields));
            var answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailAddAnswer>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            CheckAnswer(answer);

            return answer.uid;
        }

        private void CheckAnswer(AnswerBase answer)
        {
            if (answer.success == "error")
            {
                throw new Exception(answer.error);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class AnswerBase
    {
        public string success { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }

    internal class EmailAddAnswer : AnswerBase
    {
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public long uid { get; set; }
    }

    internal class EmailListAnswer : AnswerBase
    {
        public string direction { get; set; }
        public int on_page { get; set; }
        public int pages { get; set; }
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public string order { get; set; }
        public int box_limit { get; set; }
        public List<Account> accounts { get; set; }
        public object offset { get; set; }  // Описание в документации отсутствует
        public int found { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Sex
    {
        None,
        Male,
        Female
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public long uid { get; set; }
        public string iname { get; set; }
        public Sex? sex { get; set; }   // None, Male, Female, и... Null!
        public string ready { get; set; }
        public string hintq { get; set; }
        public List<string> aliases { get; set; }
        public string enabled { get; set; }
        public string maillist { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public DateTime? birth_date { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string fio { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var client = new Yandex.PDD.Client("0123456789ABCDEF01234567890ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF012");

// Получаем перечисление
var list = client.EmailList("example.com");

// И используем его как угодно..

// Например в циклах:
foreach (var account in list)
{
    // ...
}

// Или, скажем, в выборках LINQ:
var womansOfNewMillennium = 
    from account in list
    where
        account.sex == Sex.Female &&
        account.birth_date >= new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
        select account.fio;
```

Comment: Скажите, а как мне получить результат ответа делаю все на ASP, как мне вывести в Лейбл? Что-типа ящик создан или нет

Comment: @shatoidil, не совсем понял вопрос. Что именно вывести? Яндекс-почта предлагает только два возможных варианта - либо "операция выполнена успешно"(в этом случае у меня соответствующий метод успешно выполняется) либо "возникла критическая ошибка по какой-то причине"(в этом случае вываливается исключение с текстом ошибки возвращенной яндексом). Не получили исключение при вызове - выводите тупо текст наподобие "ящик успешно создан". А если получили - вы обязаны это исключение как-то обработать - как минимум выдать полученную ошибку пользователю, ну или тупо выдать что-то вроде "произошла ошибка"

Comment: Мне как показать, что возникла ошибка? Делаю так и ничего не показывает `var client = new Client(key.token);
        var uid = client.EmailAdd(key.domain, LoginTextBox.Value, PassTextBox.Value);
        Label1.Text = uid.ToString();`

Comment: @shatoidil, если ничего не показывает пользователю, то вероятно происходит какая-то ошибка в написанном вами коде для ASP.NET WebForms. К примеру, этот самый Label1 является клиентским, а не серверным контролом, и поэтому производимые вами над ним изменения на странице не отображаются. Ну а если вообще просто выдается пустая страница, то, например, у вас в настройках IIS включен запрет на выдачу ошибок в браузер и при генерации страницы происходит что-то критическое. Попробуйте пройтись по коду с включенным отладчиком.

Comment: Извините за навязчивость, но я видимо не так объясняю. Что мне нужно вывести из вашего класса, что увидеть ошибку к примеру в `MessageBox`. Или хотя бы увидеть ответ в `json`. При тестировании вашего класса я прохожу по-шагам, но после `var response`, он сразу заканчивает работу и это при любой ситуации. Еще раз извините, я новичок).@sergey-rufanov

Comment: @shatoidil, а. Тогда просто оберните вызовы в блок `try{//..} catch(Exception e){//..}`.  Если попали в catch - значит произошла ошибка, и можете внутри catch поменять текст того-же Label'а(`e.Message` при этом будет содержать текст ошибки возвращенной сервером яндекса)

Answer (score 2):

```
const string url = "https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/email/list?domain=<имя домена>";
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("PddToken","<ПДД-токен>");
var result = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: Как передать параметры ?'QueryString.Add' ?

Comment: параметры можно передавать через url (в примере domain) или так: client.QueryString.Add("name", "value");